# Why does java throw an error when we use address and pointer for the following sorting program?

Tags: java

This is a simple bubblesort program.
My doubt is with the swapping part.

```
package tutorials;

import java.util.*;

public class Bubblesort {
    //static int a[];
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner arr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter the no. of elements");
        int e=arr.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[e];
        
        for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
         a[i] = (int) arr.nextInt();
        
        int b=a.length;
        
        bubble(a,b);
        
        for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
            System.out.print(" "+a[i]);
        arr.close();
           
    }
    public static void bubble(int a[],int c){
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<c-1;j++){
                if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                    swap(&a[j],&a[j+1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void swap(int *p,int *q){
        int temp;
        temp=p;
        p=q;
        q=temp; 
    }

}
```

When I send the address and receive it through a pointer, it shows an error. Why?

Comment: Because that is not a valid java code, as java doesn't support pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is not C++.

You need to write swap differently in Java.

```
public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}
```

Java doesn't support `&` and `*` unary operators.

On the plus side you don't need to pass the length of an array

```
public static void bubble(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```